# group table item and send email

Tags: power-automate

I have an Excel table with a description column and another column with the employee.

I need a power automation that groups the employee columns and sends the email with the description.

I tried using apply to each with a matrix filter but the matrix output is blank

Comment: Oh I see your problem.

Comment: Please specify on which criteria you want to GROUP them and add some sample so that we can understand it better'